# Web-Scraping with R. Extracting rating's marks from web-page

Tags: r, web-scraping

I wnat to extract the information about rating of room(Accuracy,Communication,Cleanliness,Location, Check In,Value).

```
url <- "https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/8400275"
con <- file (url)
raw <- readLines (con)
close (con)
```

and now I need a string, that will help me to extract the information.
In source code I found such line:

```
data-reactid=".1tzzodvxlvk.1.0.0.0.0.0.3.0.0.1.0"><div class="col-lg-6"
data-reactid=".1tzzodvxlvk.1.0.0.0.0.0.3.0.0.1.0.$col-0"><div  data
reactid=".1tzzodvxlvk.1.0.0.0.0.0.3.0.0.1.0.$col-0.$Accuracy"><div
class="pull-right" data
reactid=".1tzzodvxlvk.1.0.0.0.0.0.3.0.0.1.0.$col-0.$Accuracy.0"><div
class="star-rating-wrapper" data
reactid=".1tzzodvxlvk.1.0.0.0.0.0.3.0.0.1.0.$col-0.$Accuracy.0.0">
class="star-rating" content="4.5"
```

As I understood, this is the code of "Accuracy" rating of the room.
I want to extract "The content = '4.5'" and the name of estimation "Accuracy".
How can I do that? The problem is, that in source code there are a lot of such "Content = " and "Accuracy" strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular page you could use this approach . But the code is not very robust and success for other pages depends if the structure is the same

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)

url<-"https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/8400275"
url2<-getURL(url)
parsed<-htmlParse(url2,encoding="UTF-8")
xpathSApply(parsed,"//div[@class='col-lg-6']//strong",xmlValue)[1]
xpathSApply(parsed,"//div[@class='star-rating-wrapper']//div[@class='star-rating']",xmlGetAttr,"content")[3]
```